# How can I get a pre-release org?

Tags: sandbox, pre-release, summer-18

It's that time of year again! Spring is moving to Summer and I want to get ahead with testing out Summer '18 release features. I've heard talk about pre-release orgs being available but I can't figure out how to get my hands on one. What do I need to do to qualify for a pre-release org?

Comment: As below, you can sign up for one in just over a week. If you don't already have an existing pre-release org, create a few for you and your team when the signup opens and KEEP the credentials around forever. You'll find that on every release cycle, sometime 1-2 weeks before the official signup, the old pre-release orgs upgrade early and you can play around in them. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you already had an existing pre-release org its now on SUMMER 18. You can log in and check it.
As Spring 18 pre-release program is closed(https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring18.jsp), you won't be able to create a pre-release org.

Summer 18 pre-release program has not been started yet(Page does not exist)
https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-summer18/

Keep an eye on above link to you will be able to create new pre-release org.

I believe you can raise a case to get a pre-release org or wait for your sandbox to get SUMMER18.(https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2018/04/summer-18-sandbox-preview.html) .[image]

Edit: if you stumbled upon this the pre-release org is available

https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter22/

or

```
https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-releaseName/
```

Answer (score 2):

Pre-Release Sign Up Org for Summer 18 is yet not been Opened. Below screen shot attached with Key Dates for Summer 18

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generic links that will work for all the releases in the attached document.

**Timeline Document** - https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/0694S000000ftoM

**Pre Release Org** - [sfdc.co/RR-Pre-Release](https://sfdc.co/RR-Pre-Release)